# MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread. How can I manage threads?

Tags: ios, multithreading, mapkit

I've searched similar questions, but I didn't find answer, consider my case.

I have two ViewControllers. The first one is used as a "splash screen". It fetches data from server, and performs a segue to the next vc. Everything is done on the main thread.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updatePickerInfoBeforeStart()
}

func updatePickerInfoBeforeStart() {
    self.retrieveCurrency{ [weak self] currencies in
        Currency.shared.currencies += currencies
        self?.isReadyToGo = true
        self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoadCurrency", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

The second is responsible for all action. I have just added MapKitView, and create an IBOutlet for it, when I receive such error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '<MKMapView: 0x7ff662021200; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)> initWithCoder:: MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread.'
```

It seems, that during perfoming segue from first vc to the second, but I don't know, what is wrong actually.
Moreover I have one strange bug - the loading time on the second vc of some objects, that are not used for binding data to them, on the second vc is about 30 sec.

Comment: can you please add the viewDidLoad code for the 2nd view controller?

Comment: Also, are you 100% sure that `retrieveCurrency` is dispatching its completion handler to the main queue? It's not uncommon for completion handlers (e.g. something using `URLSession` completion handlers) to run on a background thread. If doing Swift 3, in the closure you can add a line that says `dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))` to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I knew one of you mistakes. You can't perform a segue in the viewDidLoad since the current view didn't appear yet.

> Move your code to viewWillAppear method.

Comment: Correct, you can't segue while in `viewDidLoad`, but it would appear that `retrieveCurrency` runs asynchronously, likely avoiding that issue. Besides, that would not likely result in a error which says "MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread." That having been said, I agree that this code should be moved to `viewDidAppear`...

Comment: Yes, but I am not really sure that retrieveCurrency runs in background. How we can be sure about it? I said its one of the mistakes. but, I think it could cause this.

Comment: Maybe if he started by moving the code to viewWillAppear that will give us a better site to the problem.

Comment: thanks, moving to viewDidAppear solved this issue. Also, I moved retrieveCurrency  to the main queue.